# MINIX: sys_call: ipc mask denied SENDREC from 1 to 1

Tags: system-calls, stat, minix

In **MINIX 3.2.1**, I want to create a new **system call** in VFS server which will be given a filename as a parameter and will print this certain file's inode number.

So in order to retrieve the inode of the file by its name I want to use the default system call:

`int stat(char *name,struct stat *buffer)`

http://minix1.woodhull.com/manpages/man2/stat.2.html

in the body of my new system call handler which is

```
int mycall_1(void);
```

inside `/usr/src/servers/vfs/misc.c

But when I test the new system call, at the point where the `stat` system call should be invoked, it actually won't and instead it's printing the message:

> sys_call: ipc mask denied SENDREC from 1 to 1

After some research, I found that this possibly happens because the VFS server tries to send a message to itself, as `stat` is actually implemented inside VFS server, and so ipc mask denied this `sendrec()` call. So I have to edit some configuration file in order to give the right permission for this communication to happen.

But I'm not sure if what I have understood is right and also do not know which file should Ι edit to give the appropriate permissions. So, if someone could enlighten me on this issue, I would be grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understood it correctly. But the solution is not to continue "fixing the permissions" which are here just to prevent to shot yourself in the foot: it would only allow the system to more badly brocken.
Rather, you need to perform the steps that `VFS` do when it services a `STAT` request, starting after it cracked the message.

Comment: Well, I indeed solved that issue by studying the way `do_stat` works (inside /usr/src/servers/vfs/stat.c). Thanks for pointing out anyway. Another problem I encountered later in that project was that `VFS` cannot access the `inode` struct table, neither fuctions such as `get_inode`, because they 're all implemented inside `MFS` server and not `VFS`. So I had to create a new system call inside `MFS` which I invoked from the inside of `VFS`. Some info in order to create a system call to `MFS` server properly are provided here: http://www.manio.org/blog/how-to-add-new-system-calls-to-minix-3-1-8/